# Can not redirect php pages on WordPress multisite

Tags: wordpress, multisite

I have been battling redirects all day. We have a customer with an old site, and all the old php links are broken and will redirect you to a 500 error page.

I have tried 3 different 301 redirect plugins all with the same result - regular pages will redirect, and .php pages will not.

I have also tried to redirect from /folder/file(.*) - but with no succes.

This page is made on a WordPress multisite installation so i need a solution where i do not have to add all redirects in the .htaccess file.

Comment: Please provide some code.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what code you are referring to - i am using plugins to do this redirect - this is one of them i have tried https://wordpress.org/plugins/safe-redirect-manager/

Comment: @Sebastian 

This is my .htaccess at the moment - i am thinking that it must have something to do with this: 

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^wp-admin$ wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*\.php)$ $1 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]

Comment: Did you resolve this? Experiencing the same issue...